# Create tags in laravel post publishing

Tags: php, laravel

Currently when I want to add tags in my posts I have to go to my `tags page` and create them then go to my `post create` page and add them to my post by multiple input field and so far everything is working fine.

But what if I want to make my tag system works like WordPress? means I write my tags in my multiple field in my `post create page` and if that tag already exist just will be add and if not as new tag will be `save in database` and in that post as well?

Laravel version: 5.5

Update:

`PostController` note: my posts name foods as my app requires (just different naming)

Create method

```
public function create()
    {
      $ingredients = Ingredient::all();
      $vaghts = Vaght::all();
      $categories = Category::all();
      $user = Auth::user();
      return view('panel.foods.create', compact('ingredients', 'vaghts', 'user','categories'));
    }
```

Store methode

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

      //Validating title and body field
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'title'=>'required|max:225',
          'slug' =>'required|max:255',
          'user_id' =>'required|numeric',
          'image' =>'sometimes|image',
          'description' => 'required|max:100000',
          'category_id' => 'required|numeric',
          'status' => 'required|numeric',
        ));

      $food = new Food;

      $food->title = $request->input('title');
      $food->slug = $request->input('slug');
      $food->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
      $food->description = $request->input('description');
      $food->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
      $food->status = $request->input('status');



      if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = 'food' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/');
        $request->file('image')->move($location, $filename);


        $food->image = $filename;
      }

      $food->save();
      $food->vaghts()->sync($request->vaghts, false);
      $food->ingredients()->sync($request->ingredients, false);


      //Display a successful message upon save
      Session::flash('flash_message', 'Food, '. $food->title.' created');
      return redirect()->route('foods.index');
    }
```

Tags method: note: I've two different type of tags and they are the same so if I can get only one i'll do the next one myself

Create method

```
public function create()
    {
      return view('panel.vaghts.create');
    }
```

Store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      //Validating title and body field
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'title'=>'required|max:225',
        ));

      $vaght = new Vaght;

      $vaght->title = $request->input('title');

      $vaght->save();


      //Display a successful message upon save
      Session::flash('flash_message', 'Timing, '. $vaght->title.' created');
      return redirect()->route('timing.index');
    }
```

Comment: There are essentially two different ways you can do this, one is with javascript and the other is without, but either can be implemented in multiple different ways. Can you add the controller methods/routes for your post create / store and tag create / store?

Comment: @RossWilson I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first try searching which tags are already existing and which are new and then create the new tags. After that attach/sync all the tags that have been received from user.

```
//get old vaghts title
$existingVaghts = $food->vaghts->pluck('title')->toArray();

//find new vaghts
foreach($request->vaghts as $vaght) {
    if(! ( in_array($vaght, $existingVaghts) ) ) {
        //create a new vaght
        $newVaght = new App\Vaght;
        $newVaght->title = $vaght;
        $newVaght->save();
    }
}

$attachableVaghts = [];

foreach($request->vaghts as $vaght) {
    $attachableVaghts[] = App\Vaght::where('title', $vaght)->pluck('id')->first();
}

$food->vaghts()->sync($attachableVaghts);
```

That should do it I think. Hope it helps.
Check the following link for more https://codeshare.io/5Ppygd

Also for the blade template check the following link
 https://codeshare.io/axeN7R

Comment: In store method of PostController

Comment: there is some errors, 1-  `BadMethodCallException - Method lists does not exist.` 2- as my input field is select option i cannot write new tag in it.

Comment: yeah still issue with input, look at this, this is my blade select option: https://codeshare.io/5o4odb

Comment: now seems like it's working but my table is integer and new tag wouldn't be exactly integer, now i'm getting this error:     `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'TEST' for column 'vaght_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into 'food_vaght' ('food_id', 'vaght_id') values (6, TEST))`

Comment: can you please elaborate on 'my table is integer'? Didn't understand that part. Also can you show any changes to the code that I have posted, if any?

Comment: my bad bro, I assumed that I posted two different controller you'll get that the relationship between is by `id` and integer.   please see line `45 till 80`. I also commented parts so you can underestand better. thank you.   https://codeshare.io/5Ppygd

Comment: in line 48 and 65 use title instead of id's as in ` $existingIngredients = $food->vaghts->pluck('title')->toArray();`  and ` $existingIngredients = $food->ingredients->pluck('title')->toArray();` and in your blade view take option value="{{ $vaght->title }}". try it let me know if it works.

Comment: Also you are using $newVaghts outside and $newVaght inside the foreach loop same with $newIngredients. I have edited in the following link https://codeshare.io/5Ppygd

Comment: i did all those now seems like doesn't have problem with new tags but getting error of existed tags this is the error   `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'lunch' for column 'vaght_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into 'food_vaght' ('food_id', 'vaght_id') values (11, lunch))`

Comment: sorry sorry I think I misunderstood your question editing my answer right away. Don't worry, posting in a few minutes.

Comment: @mafortis check updated answer and see link https://codeshare.io/5Ppygd

Comment: Ok bro, first i did get error about `App\Vaght` so changed to  `Vaght` now when I check my database new tags will add but in front-end (blade) i will get this error `BadMethodCallException - Method attach does not exist.`  referred to `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php` line `97`     https://codeshare.io/5Ppygd

Comment: @mafortis I forgot to add () after relation name $food->vaghts()->sync($attachableVaghts); I used sync instead of attach so as to make code reusable for both store and update, although attach should also work. now answer is edited. try it.

Comment: only one issue, it does not print in front-end in blade only shows tags that has made with my tagcontroller (tags made from post create will not show in blade)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I got the simpler solution.

```
$attachableTags = [];
foreach ($request->tags as $tag) {
    $attachableTags[] = Tag::firstOrCreate([
        'name' => $tag
    ])->id;
}
$post->tags()->sync($attachableTags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you require is handled with this package

https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging

It makes setting up a tagging system as a piece of cake!
just follow the docs